# How to connect to ApacheDS with SSL?

Tags: java, apache, ssl, ldap

I need help connecting to Apache's Directory Server using SSL. I'm able to connect to the LDAP server but when I try to connect to LDAPS, I keep getting errors. I have enabled TSLv1.2 protocol in the server's configuration and still no luck. I have followed Apache's user guide exactly and still no luck!

Here is my code trying to connect using Apache's LDAP Client API:

Edit: I added the trust manager.

```
public class SecureP2P {

public static void main(String[] args) throws LdapException, IOException, NamingException {

    LdapConnectionConfig config = new LdapConnectionConfig();
    config.setLdapHost(Network.LOOPBACK_HOSTNAME);
    config.setLdapPort(10636);
    config.setUseSsl(true);
    config.setEnabledProtocols("TLSv1.2");
    config.setSslProtocol("TLSv1.2");
    config.setTrustManagers(new NoVerificationTrustManager());

    LdapConnection connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(config);
    connection.connect();
    connection.bind("uid=admin,ou=system", "secret");
    connection.unBind();
    connection.close();
}
}
```

Error Message from Client:

```
WARN : org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection - SSL 
handshake failed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:519)
atorg.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:947)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:535)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:703)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:659)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:648)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1120)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:601)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.messageReceived(SslHandler.java:360)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:500)
... 15 more    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.doTasks(SslHandler.java:793)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:567)
... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 31 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapProtocolErrorException: PROTOCOL_ERROR: The server will disconnect!
at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.message.ResultCodeEnum.processResponse(ResultCodeEnum.java:2169)
at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.AbstractLdapConnection.bind(AbstractLdapConnection.java:129)
at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.AbstractLdapConnection.bind(AbstractLdapConnection.java:112)
at edu.fau.security.network.SecureP2P.SecureP2P.main(SecureP2P.java:26)
```

Error Message from Server:

```
[13:21:10] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler] - 
Unexpected exception forcing session to close: sending disconnect notice to 
client.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:519)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:943)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:542)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:535)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:697)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:651)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:640)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1097)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:753)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.unwrapHandshake(SslHandler.java:688)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:574)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.messageReceived(SslHandler.java:359)
at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:500)
... 15 more
```

I don't get the "Certificate Unknown Exception" from the server. Even if I try using Apaches Directory Studio to connection to the server with SSL it still won't authenticate! The certificate is generated by apacheDS so I don't know what is the issue. This is really frustrating.

Comment: Did you import the server's certificate (it looks like it's self-signed) to the local, client keystore?

Comment: @JonSampson Hey Jon, thanks for the quick response. I forgot to add in my configuration that I was using a "NoVerificationTrustManager" so the client should accept any certificate without verifying it. And I also get the option to "trust" the certificate in Apache Directory Studio and still no luck. The connection is good, it's the authentication I have an issue with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. I created a certificate using Keytool and imported into the keystore for the ApacheDS configuration. I was able to get connected and authenticated through LDAPS. I just don't understand why the certificate generated by ApacheDS doesn't get accepted by Apache Directory Studio's client.

Comment: Good find. Could be that the default certificate used an algorithm that is not supported by your JVM. Seems a bit far-fetched though.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you have a case of self-signed server certificate not being accepted by the client, I recognize all the signs.

You mention a `NoVerificationTrustManager` class *(never a very good idea by the way - better create a trustmanager that reads a configured certificate or keystore)* but I doubt that it is actually used.

I think with Apache's API you need to set a specific `TrustManager` using the method `LdapConnectionConfig.setTrustManagers(TrustManager... tms)`.

Otherwise, you will have to find a way to ensure your `TrustManager` is really used.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I edited my code and added the trust manager. Still didn't work. But I did find a way to get through the LDAPS. I changed the password of the admin to be a plain text instead of with the SHA algorithm and was finally able to connect and get authenticated. But if I turned on server side password hashing shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

If we know about SSL certificate, we can use specific TrustManager impelmentaion, otherwise simply we can use as below

```
LdapConnectionConfig ldapConnectionConfig = new LdapConnectionConfig();
ldapConnectionConfig.setLdapPort(port);
ldapConnectionConfig.setLdapHost(ip);
ldapConnectionConfig.setUseSsl(useSSL);
ldapConnectionConfig.setTrustManagers(new TrustEverythingSSLTrustManager());
LdapNetworkConnection connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(ldapConnectionConfig);
```